# conditions of formation of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is it compulsory for a linear system to be homogeneous so that the solution space of that system can form a vector space? for example:will the solution space of this linear system form a vector space
[image: will the solution space of this linear system form a vector space?]

Comment: If it is not homogeneous, then all three properties should fail.  There is no way for $0$ to be a solution, if you add or scale two solutions, the RHS would also need to scale by a comparable amount.

Comment: Yes to your first question.  No to the second.  Solving an inhomogeneous equation will in general get you an **affine** space.

Comment: what 3 properties?Shouldn't a set of vectors follow 10 axioms to be defined as a vector space

Comment: thanks michael and bye-world for your comments

Comment: The three properties that ought to be met so that we can say that a subset of the vector space $\mathbf{R}^n$ is a subspace, namely that the subset in question $(1)$ contains the zero vector, $(2)$ that it is closed under addition, and $(3)$ closed under scalar multiplication.